# Change image labels .xml after resizing actual images sizes

Tags: tensorflow, image-resizing, object-detection-api, labeling

what am I doing: I've collected images for tensorflow object api retraining job, label them using labelImg application, further i've resize collected images to reduce training job time.
I guess labels generated for primary collected images are not corresponds to newly resized images, so is it any scripts how can I change previously generated images according to newly resized images. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Usually one convert the XML generated by labelImg into a single csv, then this csv is converted into a tfrecord file which contain both the images and the annotations. During this convertion coordinates are stored as relative (percentage on image width/height), thus you don't need to recalcute them. I gues this is your case too.